# Until mybatis and ibatis tags are merged, should I tag both?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, asking-questions

I suggested that [these two tags are merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70659/please-merge-ibatis-and-mybatis-tags). Until this happen, should I use both tags when asking? The "more proper" tag (mybatis) only has 19 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say it, but yes, tag with both if you have enough free tags in the question.

It will come out in the wash when a mod does the big merge (hopefully sooner rather than later).

Comment: Isn't that going to inflate the number of double-tagged questions, to do it that way?

Comment: @Grace: I'm not sure. Did they fix that code yet? In any event, it's most important to find relevant content in tag search... There are already 14 questions with both tags, so there would be a need for some editing anyway.

Comment: "We have some work to do anyway, so let's add more of it" seems less than ideal when adding more of it appears to produce limited benefit. It has a chance to increase searchability, but the period for this advantage is ideally a short one. I think the end result of spurring the merge to happen sooner will be more helpful than trying to aid people and expecting a long wait.

Comment: @Grace: I agree. It would be *best* if they fixed the duplicate tags problem when merging... in which case it wouldn't matter. Getting some mod attention towards these less popular requests would be nice, too.